# How to refresh config clients automatically?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-config

I am new to Spring Config Server/Client technologies.
I am using a spring config server to hold some config values.
Config clients will connect to the server and get the values.

If i change some of the config values at the config server, then currently I have to refresh the clients to load the config details from config server again by invoking "/refresh" on each client.

Is there anyway the clients will be notified by the config server and they will then reload the configuration again ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way.

The solution is to use the Spring Cloud Bus. Using this module, you would link multiple clients to the server using a message broker. [The only message broker implementation currently supported by this module is AMQP.](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-bus) Once the clients are connected to the server, invoking the endpoint on the server `/bus/refresh` will automatically broadcast the configuration changes to all the subscribed clients. This therefore means it is possible to reload configuration changes for any number of clients with one *single* refresh request which originates at the server.

Comment: But still it needs to be explicitly invoked - "/bus/refresh".  Is there anyway if config server will automatically detect that git repository is changed and will invoke refresh on connected clients?

Comment: There is no other way. You need to use Spring Cloud Bus.

Comment: @RahulVedpathak If you really need that functionality, you could poll the repository every few seconds for changes, and in the event of a change being detected, you would invoke the specified endpoint. This is an ugly solution so be aware of the drawbacks of this e.g. using up bandwidth

Comment: spring-cloud-config-monitor allows for webhooks to automatically send refresh messages over the bus